# what does the desktop entry file '*.directory' actually do?

Tags: unity

I think the title is clear enough. I cannot find what the `*.directory` files actually do in on [freedesktop specifications](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html).

Also I have another question, `*.desktop` files can have categories, but what is the point of the categories?

For example, `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop` has **Categories:Development;IDE;**. Since it is tagged **IDE**, there should be a way I can filter the desktop entries so that only the specific entry of chosen category is shown. But I can't find such a way.

By the way, I am using Ubuntu16.04, unity.

---

**Edit**

For those wonder how to customize categories like me, I found one solution on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177212/add-new-category-to-applications)

Comment: Some DEs use menus, and the categories come into play there (e.g., cinnamon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWKzv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*.directory` files and *Categories* inside `*.desktop` files are used to categorize things and to prevent chaos - see GNOME Shell for comparison:

[image: GNOME Shell]

They allow to have well-organized categorized lists of applications - see screenshots of current desktop environments below:

- Cinnamon

  [image: cinnamon]
- GNOME FlashBack

  [image: gnome flashback]
- KDE / Plasma

  [image: kde]
- LXDE

  [image: lxde]
- MATE DE

  [image: mate]
- Xfce

  [image: xfce]